# React router link is not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have build a profile page which should render the content of the component by getting the user_id from the URL using react router.

`<PrivateRoute exact path='/profile/:user_id' component={ProfilePage} />`

This works quite fine.

But....

If I open any profile page by changing the URL and then click on my menu item to bring me back to the current users profile page it won't re-render the content of the component.
But the URL of the browser changes.

```
<Dropdown.Item
    as={Link}
    to={`/profile/${user.user_id}`}
    text='My profile'
  />
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

**Profilepage.js**

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { deleteHotel, getHotelsByUserID } from "../../actions/hotel";
import { Grid, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";
import ProfileHeader from "./ProfileHeader";
import ProfileContent from "./ProfileContent";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { getProfileByCurrentUserID } from "../../actions/profile";

export default function ProfilePage({ match }) {
  const { auth } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));
  const { token } = auth;
  const [hotels, setHotels] = useState([]);
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAllHotel();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProfile();
  }, []);

  const loadAllHotel = async () => {
    let res = await getHotelsByUserID(token, match.params.user_id);
    setHotels(res.data);
  };

  const loadProfile = async () => {
    let res = await getProfileByCurrentUserID(token, match.params.user_id);
    setProfile(res.data);
  };

  const handleHotelDelete = async (hotel_id) => {
    try {
      await deleteHotel(token, hotel_id);
      toast.success("Hotel deleted");
      loadAllHotel();
      loadProfile();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      toast.error("Cannot delete hotel");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Grid.Column width={16}>
        <Segment.Group>
          <ProfileHeader match={match} profile={profile} />
          <ProfileContent
            match={match}
            hotels={hotels}
            handleHotelDelete={handleHotelDelete}
          />
        </Segment.Group>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

**SignedInMenu.js**

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Image, Dropdown, Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";
import avatar from "../img/stevie.jpg";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function SignedInMenu() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const { auth } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));
  const { user } = auth;

  const logout = () => {
    console.log("LOGOUT");
    dispatch({
      type: "LOGOUT",
      payload: null,
    });
    window.localStorage.removeItem("auth");
    history.push("/signin");
  };
  return (
    <Menu.Item position='right'>
      <Image avatar spaced='right' src={avatar} />
      <Dropdown pointing='top left' text={user.user_name}>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item
            as={Link}
            to='/hotel/new'
            text='New Hotel'
            // icon='plus'
          />
          <Dropdown.Item
            as={Link}
            // to='/profile/me'
            to={`/profile/${user.user_id}`}
            text='My profile'
            // icon='user'
          />
          <Dropdown.Item
            // as={Link}
            // to='/placeholder'
            text='My account'
            // icon='user'
          />
          <Dropdown.Item text='Sign out' icon='power' onClick={logout} />
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </Menu.Item>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

// css
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import "./App.css";

// components
import NavBar from "./components/navigation/Navbar";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import HotelDashboard from "./components/hotels/HotelDashboarrd";
import NewHotel from "./components/hotels/NewHotel";
import ProfilePage from "./components/profiles/ProfilePage";
import ProfileStatistics from "./components/profiles/ProfileStatistics";

function App() {
  const { auth } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar />
      <ToastContainer />
      <Switch>
        <>
          <Route exact path='/signin'>
            {auth ? <Redirect to='/home' /> : <Login />}
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/signup'>
            {auth ? <Redirect to='/home' /> : <Register />}
          </Route>

          <Container className='main'>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/home' component={HotelDashboard} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/hotel/new' component={NewHotel} />
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path='/profile/:user_id'
              component={ProfilePage}
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path='/profile/statistics'
              component={ProfileStatistics}
            />
          </Container>
        </>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share the file where routes are, but if I understand when you change from `/profile/1` to `/profile/2` the component is not remounted. Maybe, you need using key atribute with param ID used in the route path to achieve that:

```
<PrivateRoute
  exact
  path='/profile/:user_id'
  component={(props) => (
    <ProfilePage
      {...props}
      key={props.match.params.user_id}
    />
  )}
/>
```

When you change url directly from `/profile/1` to `/profile/2` the current route keeps the same, then component is not remounted. If you add the key attribute to your Route, ReactJs listens to key changes and force the remounting when they happen, in your case, when `user_id` changes from 1 to 2.

Comment: I have edited my initial comment. Please have a look.

Comment: OK. Try remove `<Container className='main'>` that wrap your private routes and include the key attribute as I explain in solution.

Comment: How do I need to change my code to make this worK? If I add match.params.user_id to my App.js I will get undefined back.

Comment: Sorry, I did the adjustments in the solution now!

Comment: Perfect. This works.. Could you maybe explain in some words what exacty was the issue and why didnt it worked out before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now, I've added the explanation inside the solution.