# react redux lead to infinite loop while using useeffect and dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, infinite-loop, use-effect, dispatch

I deleted my initial question because it was not very well explained from my side and led to unnecessary discuission and lost focus.

I am trying to build an app with react and redux and got stuck in an infinite loop while using useEffect and dispatch.

I build a codesandbox to reproduce the issue. Here is my work.
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-morning-ew161
It seems like the issue is somehow related to line 8 in App.js but I can't explain why and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not write `useSelector` calls like that.
See https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates

Instead of

```js
const { auth } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));
```

write

```js
const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
```

Your other problem is

```js
              component={(props) => (
                <TestProfilePage {...props} key={props.match.params.user_id} />
              )}
```

this will create a new component on every rerender and React will unmount the full component tree and create a new one, effectively re-running your `useEffect`. Instead of `component`, use `render`. Also see the react-router docs on that.

Your code does two things:

- it returns a new object on every selector call, which will make your component rerender *always*, even if there is no state change
- it returns the full state, so even if you just returned `state` without the spread, it would rerender at any state change.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I already tried render instead of of component but this approach didn't solved following issue I had before. Using component was the result of below question. 
See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67731146/react-router-link-is-not-re-rendering-component/67732497?noredirect=1#comment119740268_67732497

Comment: You can also stay with `component`, but you will have to declare that component as a top-level function in your file, not inline.

Comment: Changing to const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);  solved the infinite loop. Please consider that I am quite new to coding. Could you please explain what you mean with 
"you will have to declare that component as a top-level function in your file, not inline". maybe with a code example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not write it in your component.

Write outside of your component `const MyComponent = (props) => (<TestProfilePage {...props} key={props.match.params.user_id} />)` and do `component={MyComponent}`.

As it is *outside* your component, that will only be executed once and stay **the same component**. If you write it in your component, it will always be a component with the same behaviour, but every time a new component.

Comment: I a m a bit confused but we are close to solve it. 
Where exactly do I need to write `const MyComponent = (props) => (<TestProfilePage {...props} key={props.match.params.user_id} />)`?? In my App.js?
Could you may edit you initial post please.

Comment: Anywhere inside your file that is not between `function App(){` and the corresponding `}`. Preferrably above it, probably.

Comment: I have marked your answer as the solution. Thanks for your input.